# When pushing from other PC, other user is displayed

Tags: git, github

When I push changes via git to GitHub from my job PC, it shows different user in commit history. I use same username and password when git asks me for remote login info. None of these commits (from my workplace) are recorded as mine in profile page commits map.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure your username and email are properly setup on your local repository. Check out Githubs [help page](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-username-in-git/).

you will use the following commands:

`git config user.name "Your Name"`
`git config user.email "your@email.com"`

Comment: Do I need to do this for each repo? Is there approach to set it up globally?

Comment: you can set it up globally for all local repos with  `git config --global user.name "your name"`

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add one more point along with `@g19fanatic` answer.

- You need to add to add SSH Keys into your github account.

Comment: It was not necessary in my case.